# MySQL LEFT JOIN with SUM before a date and SUM before and at that date

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have three tables (pagu, realisasi and perencanaan). I'm using left join. I want to sum one field before a certain date while for another field sum before and at that date.

My pagu table:

```
idpagu  kode    komponen    pagu    target_kinerja  tahun   keterangan
1   2217.057.056    Pengembangan Sistem Manajemen Mutu UPTP     52740000    1   2017    tes123
2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     4732755000  120     2017    tes123
3   2220.052.051    Calon Wirausaha Baru yang Dilatih (RM)  12464938000     240     2017    TES123
```

[image: my pagu table]

My realisasi table:

```
idrealisasi     idpagu  kode    komponen    realisasi   target_kinerja  tgl     keterangan
5   1   2217.057.056    Pengembangan Sistem Manajemen Mutu UPTP     52740000    1   1/14/2017   tes
6   2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     10000000    10  1/14/2017   tes
7   2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     20000000    20  2/14/2017   tes2
8   2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     10000000    10  3/14/2017   tes3
9   2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     10000000    10  6/14/2017   tes4
10  2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     10000000    10  1/15/2017   tes
```

[image: my realisasi table]

My perencanaan table (no records):

```
idperencanaan   idpagu  kode    komponen    penarikan   target_kinerja  tgl     keterangan
```

[image: my perencanaan table]

My query:

```
select p.idpagu,p.kode,p.komponen,p.pagu,p.target_kinerja,
if(pr.penarikan is null,0,sum(pr.penarikan)) as perenuang,
if(pr.target_kinerja is null,0,sum(pr.target_kinerja)) as perenfis,
if(r.realisasi is null,0,sum(r.realisasi)) as realuang,
if(r.target_kinerja is null,0,sum(r.target_kinerja)) as realfis,
p.pagu-if(r.realisasi is null,0,sum(r.realisasi)) as sisauang,
p.target_kinerja-if(r.target_kinerja is null,0,sum(r.target_kinerja)) as sisafis,
if(sum(rr.realisasi) is null,0,sum(rr.realisasi)) as tes
from pagu p 
left join realisasi r on p.idpagu=r.idpagu and r.tgl BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-01-15"
left join perencanaan pr on p.idpagu=pr.idpagu and r.tgl BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-01-15"
left join realisasi rr on p.idpagu=rr.idpagu and rr.tgl < "2017-01-15"
group by p.idpagu,r.idpagu,rr.idpagu
```

My result:

```
idpagu  kode    komponen    pagu    target_kinerja  perenuang   perenfis    realuang    realfis     sisauang    sisafis     tes
1   2217.057.056    Pengembangan Sistem Manajemen Mutu UPTP     52740000    1   0   0   52740000    1   0   0   52740000
2   2220.051.051    Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas     4732755000  120     0   0   20000000    20  4712755000  100     20000000
3   2220.052.051    Calon Wirausaha Baru yang Dilatih (RM)  12464938000     240     0   0   0   0   12464938000     240     0
```

[image: my query]

My question:

The tes column is pagu - realuang before the current date "2017-01-15", and the second row should be 10.000.000, but my query gives 20.000.000.
How do I write my query so that in the second record the tes column is 10.000.000?

My schema:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `pagu`;
CREATE TABLE `pagu` (
  `idpagu` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `komponen` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `pagu` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_kinerja` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tahun` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `keterangan` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpagu`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `pagu` VALUES ('1', '2217.057.056', 'Pengembangan Sistem Manajemen Mutu UPTP', '52740000', '1', '2017', 'tes123');
INSERT INTO `pagu` VALUES ('2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '4732755000', '120', '2017', 'tes123');
INSERT INTO `pagu` VALUES ('3', '2220.052.051', 'Calon Wirausaha Baru yang Dilatih (RM)', '12464938000', '240', '2017', 'TES123');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `perencanaan`;
CREATE TABLE `perencanaan` (
  `idperencanaan` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idpagu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `komponen` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `penarikan` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_kinerja` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tgl` date NOT NULL,
  `keterangan` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idperencanaan`),
  KEY `fk_perencanaan_pagu1_idx` (`idpagu`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_perencanaan_pagu1` FOREIGN KEY (`idpagu`) REFERENCES `pagu` (`idpagu`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `realisasi`;
CREATE TABLE `realisasi` (
  `idrealisasi` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idpagu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kode` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `komponen` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `realisasi` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_kinerja` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tgl` date NOT NULL,
  `keterangan` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idrealisasi`),
  KEY `fk_perencanaan_pagu1_idx` (`idpagu`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_perencanaan_pagu10` FOREIGN KEY (`idpagu`) REFERENCES `pagu` (`idpagu`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('5', '1', '2217.057.056', 'Pengembangan Sistem Manajemen Mutu UPTP', '52740000', '1', '2017-01-14', 'tes');
INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('6', '2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '10000000', '10', '2017-01-14', 'tes');
INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('7', '2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '20000000', '20', '2017-02-14', 'tes2');
INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('8', '2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '10000000', '10', '2017-03-14', 'tes3');
INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('9', '2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '10000000', '10', '2017-06-14', 'tes4');
INSERT INTO `realisasi` VALUES ('10', '2', '2220.051.051', 'Pelatihan Peningkatan Produktivitas', '10000000', '10', '2017-01-15', 'tes');
```

Comment: thank you for your fast respond @philipxy. you're right sum before and sum at certain date. i have add schema and code snipet (my table is quite long) so users can copy paste it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please: Don't use links. Don't use images. Even for an ER diagram, give the info in text too. If your question isn't re php/html/javascript, don't use snippets. Edit your code in as a "code block". (Indent 4 spaces or click on "{}".) Go to sqlfiddle.com. (No fixed site for other languages.) Query to show your table values. Run your query. Edit the sqlfiddle link into your question. You *could* also include sqlfiddle output re-formatted with aligned columns in a code block; or you could format your code's INSERT VALUES to have aligned columns. (Aligned = human readable.)

Comment: Please don't keep old unclear text; edit your question to be clear. All your original text is unclear. In my last comment I guessed that two parts said the same thing; but I don't know what that is. I can't understand your new description either. Say things in small steps. Also, you are still only describing what you want via an example. But an example of what? Try to tell us what a row says when it's in a table. Re examples: Please read [mcve]. What is your *desired* output table? Maybe use a simpler/edited example that just shows your problem/needs.

Comment: I guess you mean tes = pagu - ("sisauang before the current date") = pagu - (pagu - ("realuang before the current date")), ie tes = "realuang before the current date"? Unfortunately that's still just word salad. You mean that tes for a given pagu and (current) date is the sum of that pagu's realisasi values for days before the date. If you force yourself to thing/write what you really mean you start to think/write clearly. PS The original text query you gave was different than the text at the link you gave. I have copied it from the link into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your query and table & column names (pagu = ceiling, realisasi = actual, perencanaan = planned), for each ceiling you are summing its actual values on days in a certain range, its planned values on those days, its actual values on some of those days, and some related target values, treating NULL values as 0.

I assume that if a ceiling has an actual value on a date then it has a planned value on that date. Otherwise, your query would involve FULL JOIN, and a LEFT JOIN would wrongly sometimes form rows with different dates, etc. So I suspect you are missing a FK (foreign key).

Your first LEFT JOIN gets the actual value for each ceiling for some dates. Then you want any planned value for a *ceiling & date*. So you are missing `and r.tgl = pr.tgl`. Then you want any actual value for a *ceiling & date* for some of those dates. So your third LEFT JOIN is missing `and r.tgl = rr.tgl`.

You are grouping & summing incorrectly. If a SELECT uses a column outside an aggregate call then it should be single-valued for each subrow of GROUPed columns. (GROUP BY returns one row per subrow of GROUPed columns.) (`SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` disallows MySQL's non-standard behaviour.)

```
select p.idpagu, count(*), p.pagu, p.target_kinerja,
    sum(coalesce(pr.penarikan,0)) as pr_penarikan,
    sum(coalesce(pr.target_kinerja,0)) as pr_target_kinerja,
    sum(coalesce(r.realisasi,0)) as r_realisasi,
    sum(coalesce(r.target_kinerja,0)) as r_target_kinerja,
    p.pagu-sum(coalesce(r.realisasi,0)) as d_realisasi,
    p.target_kinerja-sum(coalesce(r.target_kinerja,0)) as d_target_kinerja,
    sum(coalesce(rr.realisasi,0)) as rr_realisasi
from pagu p
left join realisasi r on p.idpagu=r.idpagu and r.tgl BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-01-15"
left join perencanaan pr on p.idpagu=pr.idpagu and r.tgl = pr.tgl and r.tgl BETWEEN "2017-01-01" and "2017-01-15"
left join realisasi rr on p.idpagu=rr.idpagu and r.tgl = rr.tgl and r.tgl < "2017-01-15"
group by p.idpagu, p.pagu, p.target_kinerja;
```

```
idpagu  pagu                    pr_penarikan    r_realisasi     d_realisasi             rr_target_kinerja 
    count(*)        target_kinerja  pr_target_kinerja       r_target_kinerja    d_target_kinerja    
1   1   52740000    1           0   0           52740000    1   0               0       52740000
2   2   4732755000  120         0   0           20000000    20  4712755000      100     10000000
3   1   12464938000 240         0   0           0           0   12464938000     240     0
```